# Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, electron

I am new to websockets. I tried to create a websocket with the following address ws://localhost:8000 in order to send data continuously from my python program to a js program which takes care of retrieving them and displaying them in boxes. At the beginning, when I put this address it did not work and show me the following error: `Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I had to put my IPV4 address instead of localhost for it to work. Except that I tried to restart my program with the previous address and it worked. I have absolutely no idea why I no longer have the error I had previously?

I also specify that all this is developed using electron.

Here is my python and js code :

**Python** :

```
import asyncio
import random
import datetime
import websockets
import json

async def handler(websocket, path):
    while True:
        data = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10)]
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(data))
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

start_server = websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 8000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**JS** :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Home from './pages/home';


export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');

    socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      setData(JSON.parse(event.data));
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
            <div class="home">
                <div class="template-1" id="temp1">
                <div class="panel-1">
                    <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1>Panel 1</h1>
                    <i class='bx bx-cog modal-trigger-panel'></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="sec-5 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-5">
                        {data ? <span class="h1" id="h1-fs-s5">{data[0]}</span> : <p>Loading...</p>}
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s5</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-4 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-4">
                        {data ? <span class="h1" id="h1-fs-s5">{data[1]}</span> : <p>Loading...</p>}
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s4</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-3 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-3">
                        {data ? <span class="h1" id="h1-fs-s5">{data[2]}</span> : <p>Loading...</p>}
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s3</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-2 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-2">
                        {data ? <span class="h1" id="h1-fs-s5">{data[3]}</span> : <p>Loading...</p>}
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s2</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec-1 modal-trigger-data" id="hs-sec-1">
                        {data ? <span class="h1" id="h1-fs-s5">{data[4]}</span> : <p>Loading...</p>}
                        <h2>TWIST</h2>
                        <h3>s1</h3>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Regards,